# How to measure power consumption with a hall effect sensor?

Tags: microcontroller, electromagnetism, physics

I am trying to make a project in which power usage of our daily life devices such as refrigerators, television etc will be measured using a Hall effect sensor and a microcontroller (ARM Cortex-M TM4C1233H6PM series).

I know how the Hall voltage is measured using the sensor but I do not understand how should I connect it with my micro-controller and also how can the data from this sensor (Hall Voltage) be used to find out the power?

I know that this might seem like a very basic question but any help is much appreciated. If you know of any good resources then kindly refer them to me as well so I can learn it better.

Comment: hall-effect sensor modules are designed to spit out 0-5v, ideal for many MCU's ADC...

Comment: Yes but how should I calculate the power from Hall voltage measured?

Comment: typically it floats at 2.5v and the vendor provides a conversion to amps, which mostly depends on the max of the sensor (ex 5a, 25a) to bring it to 0 or 5v. you can also self-calibrate it with a DMM; it's a linear scale, so it's very easy to extrapolate after making two measurements. byt the vendor should give you a sample code, or get on from the web; it's pretty simple compared to most problems.